# Install intl.so with Mamp PRO

Tags: mamp, intl

I follow this ticket : http://blog.geertvd.be/2011/05/18/installing-the-intl-extension-on-mamp/.

When i reboot my MAMP server, and i execute a phpinfo(), the intl extension was not loaded.

I don't understand why. I have completed the good php.ini file (In my case : /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.14/conf/php.ini, and i have the moved the intl.so) I have no error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my problem.  In fact i use MAMP Pro, and to edit php.ini file we have to click on File > Edit Config > Php ... And your configuration is ok after a restart !